# Unexpected results from Elasticsearch

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch, logstash

I have some documents stored in ES (by logstash). and the results, when querying ES, do not look right:

The first query (see the queries and the results below) is supposed(meant) to return *only* documents that do not contain `region` field.

Even further, based on the result of the first query , obviously there is a document that contains field `region`, however, the results for second query which should (at least) return a document with `region=IN`, contains no documents.

- Is something wrong with my queries?
- How can I investigate where the problem is? (The ES logs do not have anything related to these queries)

Here is the query:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash*/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    filter : {
        "and" : [
            { "term" : { "type" : "xsys" } },
            { "missing" : { "field" : "region" } }
        ]
    }, size: 2
}'
```

And the result:

```
{
  "took" : 40,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 90,
    "successful" : 90,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5747,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "logstash-2013.09.28",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "UMrz9bwKQgCq__TwBT0WmQ",
      "_score" : 1.0, 
      "_source" : {
        .....
        "type":"xsys",
        ....
        "region":"IN",
        }
    }, { ....
    } ]
  }
}
```

Furthermore, the result for the following query:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash*/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
    filter : { "term" : { "region" : "IN" } },
    size: 1
}'
```

is:

```
{
  "took" : 55,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 90,
    "successful" : 90,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
```

The following mapping is used:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/logstash_per_index -d '
{
    "template": "logstash*",
    "settings": {
        "index.query.default_field": "message",
        "index.cache.field.type": "soft",
        "index.store.compress.stored": true
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": { "enabled": false },
            "properties": {
                "message": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed" },
                "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                "type": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                ....
                "region": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Mapping (what ES has returned - `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2013.09.28/_mapping`):

```
{
   "logstash-2013.09.28":{
      "logs":{
         "_all":{
            "enabled":false
         },
         "properties":{
            "@timestamp":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "@version":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "omit_norms":true,
               "index_options":"docs"
            },
            "message":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "region":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "type":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "omit_norms":true,
               "index_options":"docs"
            }
         }
      },
      "_default_":{
         "_all":{
            "enabled":false
         },
         "properties":{
            "@timestamp":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "@version":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "omit_norms":true,
               "index_options":"docs"
            },
            "message":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "type":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "omit_norms":true,
               "index_options":"docs"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is you field region indexed? Can you post your mapping please?

Comment: @javanna I've added the mapping

Comment: in the second query, if i use `match` instead of `term`, i get results.

Comment: Yep good point, I'm afraid your _default_ mapping in the template is not getting applied, thus the region field is analyzed (lowercased). You would get a result for it using the term filter but querying for `in` lowercased. Can you confirm?

Comment: No, even for lowercase `in` dose not work. However, if i use `us` (i have documets with `US`) i get results.

Comment: Cool...can you post your real mapping instead of the template? I would like to see the mapping that gets applied to your region field.

Comment: Actually, there is no mapping! ... I did `PUT` for the mapping again, i got `200` result, but no mapping got created for the `region` field

Comment: @javanna posted (the relevant part of) the mapping returned by ES

Comment: The document you got was returned from index logstash-2013.09.28, which I suspect has a different mapping :) that one has the region field I guess

Comment: @javanna `18` was typo (sorry!) `28` does have mapping, and it is `analysed`. Why the new mapping does not apply?

Comment: ... but still i dont understand the results returned

Comment: for the in part, I had the exact same problem. "In" is a stop word in the default analyzer. The analyzer used for yours fields is the default analyzer, and elasticsearch WILL NOT allow you to change it dynamically. Once an analyzer is set for a field, it is set for good. I think you'll have to reindex with a new mapping"

Comment: When having problems, always use the analyze API to see the actual tokens ES would store for your input document. A filter would not be analyzed, so it will have to be an exact match in the query body to the stored token. localhost:9200/logstash-2013.09.28/_analyze?[type_name].field=region&text=IN

Comment: Here are a list of the default stop_words that come with the standard analyzer:  
      "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
      "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
      "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
      "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
      "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"